# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn: Get ValueMember

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGrid with a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn that has a datasource. I need to get the ValueMember from the selected item.
Heres the code that binds it:

```
        private void DgvWorkBars_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = Settings.Default.ProdConnectionString;
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connection;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT DESCRIPTION,NUM FROM dbo.DIMENSIONS WHERE DIMENSIONCODE = 1";
        SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sqlDa.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            sqlDa.Fill(ds, "DIMENSIONS");
            DataRow nRow = ds.Tables["DIMENSIONS"].NewRow();
            ds.Tables["DIMENSIONS"].Rows.InsertAt(nRow, 0);

            //Binding the data to the combobox.
            ClnDivision.DataSource = ds.Tables["DIMENSIONS"].DefaultView;
            connection.Close();

            ClnDivision.DisplayMember =
                ds.Tables["DIMENSIONS"].Columns["DESCRIPTION"].ToString();

            ClnDivision.ValueMember =
                ds.Tables["DIMENSIONS"].Columns["NUM"].ToString();

   }
```

I tried to get it using:

```
string division = ((DataGridView)sender)[0,e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString();
```

This gives me the DisplayMember, or "Description" I need the corresponding "NUM" value

Answer (score 0):

ugh. easy after more experimentation:

```
((DataGridView)sender)[0,e.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
```